# How to select installing packages via DVD while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, package-management, dvd

I am new to Ubuntu (or Linux). I have just started to get acquainted with Fedora and now I want to switch to Ubuntu. I was wondering if I install via DVD, will all the packages (including developmental tools) get installed or is there any way to select certain packages?

I want to select a list of tools to install rather than install them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is possible in two ways, and I'll give you the most straightforward way.

- First, make a LiveCD/DVD
- Secondly, boot the LiveCD/DVD
- Before running the installation, install an programs you want to be included in your actual installation (if it is a large set of programs, you need to have a substantial amount of RAM, because the LiveCD/DVD uses the RAM as a "drive" for storing information.
- Once you have installed all that you want, install the system as usual using the Ubuntu installer.

You should now have a preconfigured system with all the software you want.